# Storyboard initial viewcontroller doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

My app is in swift using story board. After launch file my app start the initial view controller the one I have already set the entry point. But suddenly my app doesn't appear the initial viewcontroller after the Launching screen.but if I set the entry point to another view controller its appear. The first viewcontroller `viewdidload` and all other `UITableView` delegates and datasource are running when Idebug but the screen doesnt come it just keep staying on my launch file.

What would be the reason for this? Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
import UIKit

class SubscriptionViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tblSettings: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var vwTitle: UIView!
var mutableDictionary :[String]=["Business","News","Sports","Entertainment","Crime","Politics"]
var imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tblSettings.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    tblSettings.delegate=self
    tblSettings.dataSource=self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mutableDictionary.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SettingsCell") as! SettingsTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil
    {
        //tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UICustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UICustomTableViewCell")
        tableView.registerClass(SettingsTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SettingsCell")

        cell = SettingsTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "SettingsCell")

    }
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    // Custom view options
    let image=UIImage.init(named: "SettingsUnChecked")

    imageView.image=image

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    cell.accessoryView = imageView//UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))

    cell.accessoryView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    if let label = cell.lblName{
        label.text = mutableDictionary[indexPath.row]
        label.textColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    return cell

}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: could you please post some of your code so we can have more information about your question

Comment: Your controller is marked as "Initial Controller" in the attributes?

Comment: yeas I marked it,, please check I updated my question with my initial viewcontroller code. This is full code of my initial viewcontroller

Comment: Try to comment this line:
  `tblSettings.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()`

Comment: Check that the name of the storyboard is correctly set in main interface under general tab

Comment: How can I check that? Can ypu please explain me?

Comment: @HoracioGarza I tried but same :(

Comment: @AhmadIshfaqYeas, its Main.Storyboard

Comment: here I found the issue is with tblsettings.datasource=self. when I commented it the view appears. why is that?

Comment: seems your view is always appearing but data is not populating. Try overriding viewDidAppear and put a break point. If it hits your view is appearing.